# Foundation Tooltip top positioning

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to setup Tooltips from Foundation to work with images on my site but I have a problem there.

Tooltip should appear on top of the image but at the moment it seems to appear from half of image height, thus covering half of image.

How can I affect positioning of tooltips?

Comment: Which version of Foundation are you using? Could you please post the code you're using and possibly a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) example?

Comment: you can set the position using data attribute, please check the documentation according to your Foundation version.

Comment: It's foundation 5, but I think someone before me messed with foundation.js or CSS as top and bottom positioning is totally wrong. It doesn't even display correctly on blank page when set on text so I guess I have to do a lot of debugging